# Publish an app for Office that is packaged as an autohosted app for SharePoint Online Portal

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, office365-apps, office-app

My aim is develop an excel application and use it on my sharepoint online 2013 portal. So I developed an excel task pane app on napa. I downloaded it for visual studio and open it on visual studio 2012. After that I changed it's project type from app for office to auto hosted app for sharepoint and I publish it, got .app file. Than I opened my sharepoint online portal app catalog site and upload my .app file to apps for sharepoint library. You can see my app(AddressCleaner) from below image.

[image]

After all of these steps I went site content and click add an app. But I can't see my app in available apps. I can't find any solution. Actually I followed this ->[post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj692556(v=office.15).aspx)

What I'm missing? Is any suggestion as to what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I didn't understand its cause but it was solved. I downloaded my project again from napa and changed its package type in visual studio. After than i uploaded it to apps for sharepoint library in app catalog site. I installed it. Than i added my catalog site as trusted site to excel file and inserted my app. Thats all.